# facebook unity sdk 7.0.1 issue

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I update the facebook plugin for unity to 7.0.1 but I'm getting a warning "Cannot find Facebook SDK Version" also when I run the project after setting the App Id I'm getting the following error in `Assets/Facebook/Scripts/PlatformEditor/EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs:22`

> You cannot show two modal windows at once
>   UnityEngine.GUI:ModalWindow(Int32, Rect, WindowFunction, String)
>   EditorFacebookAccessToken:OnGUI() (at
>   Assets/Facebook/Scripts/PlatformEditor/EditorFacebookAccessToken.cs:22)

The line on which I'm getting error is

```
GUI.ModalWindow(
        GetHashCode(), 
        new Rect(windowLeft, windowTop, windowWidth, windowHeight), 
        OnGUIDialog, 
        "Unity Editor Facebook Login");
```

Comment: About the version warning - checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31049562/3086454).

Answer (score 2):

i go the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806008/error-cannot-find-facebook-sdk-version?s=1%7C3.1641) and i have no idea, wait for [official](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/388194098041651) sdk because the 7.x is on beta version right now